# how can i improve script execution time

Tags: scripting, performance

Is it there a control or something to assign more resources to script execution. Or the only option is to improve script's code performance?.

Answer (score 2):

If blender freezes while script execution, you should check performance using [build-in modules](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Tools/Debugging/Python_Profile).

In some cases you can cache function return using [functools.lru_cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

The one way to get more resources is using [multiprocessing](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32779/23459).